# Can't upload media files django on digital ocean

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, django-deployment

I've recently deployed a django app on digital ocean. Everything works perfectly fine until I try to create an object containing an image. I get an error saying Server Error (500).

**Here is what I've tried to do :**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name ****;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/joseph/hacka;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/joseph/hacka;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}
}
```

**Here is my settings.py code :**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Unfortunately, that hasn't work out.
Please help me if you know the anwer to my problem.

**Update**:
I have found the problem with my code: when I turn debug to True, I get an error saying
`errno 13: Permission denied.`

However, I don not know how to fix this.

Please help me if you can.

Comment: What does the error log of Nginx shows?

Comment: it says that I don't  it can't find some bootstrap files that have nothing to do with my problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is because of the media file.
Did you check the `media` settings?

You need to check in the settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: That's not the problem. It's exactly what I have

Comment: Are you trying to serve static files using djngo?

Comment: What do you mean? In my urls ?

Comment: Suppose you have abc.jpg in the server. Now to access that jpg file you would use http://example.com/abc.jpg. Is your django server meant only for this purpose?

Comment: I can successfully access to my static and media files, but I can't upload any media files form the webiste.

Comment: Is it getting saved? Can you edit the question and put the view code?

Comment: What do you mean by getting saved? What are you talking about? And which view code?

Comment: When you upload a media file , it needs to be saved in the server

Comment: Is it located in my settings.py file ?

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html follow this guide

Answer (score 0):

Just remove '/' from MEDIA_URL in setting.py like this
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

Answer (score 0):

I may have faced similar issue. My setup is Gunicorn running behind Nginx. When uploading a file to django media library, the request does not show up in Gunicorn's access log. That means it is stopped by Nginx and a 500 error code was returned. Further search led to this site, https://killtheradio.net/technology/nginx-returns-error-on-file-upload/ , which solved my problem.

Basically, Nginx temporarily saves file body to disk at `/var/lib/nginx/client_body`. But this folder was not accessible to the Nginx process. A simple chown solved the problem then.